# Get property ID in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, properties, winforms

I have images in Resources, and I'd like to get their ID.
I dont find the following code from MSDN to be very helpful.

How did it get the number 20624 and 20625?

If I have image accessible with `Properties.Resources.Image1` , how can I programmatically get its ID?

```
private void DemonstratePropertyItem(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Create two images.
    Image image1 = Image.FromFile("c:\\FakePhoto1.jpg");
    Image image2 = Image.FromFile("c:\\FakePhoto2.jpg");

    // Get a PropertyItem from image1.
    PropertyItem propItem = image1.GetPropertyItem(20624);

    // Change the ID of the PropertyItem.
    propItem.Id = 20625;

    // Set the PropertyItem for image2.
    image2.SetPropertyItem(propItem);

    // Draw the image.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image2, 20.0F, 20.0F);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSDN provides a [list of propertyitem ids in hexdecimal format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id.aspx) and their corresponding tags.

In your example, 20624 (0x5090) is `PropertyTagLuminanceTable` and 20625(0x5091) is `PropertyTagChrominanceTable`

Edit:
Just a note, those IDs are not to access the images themselves, but rather metadata about the image.

Comment: I totally misunderstood what propertyitem ids are for. I thought the id identifies the image, and I can retrieve them using int propId.

Thanks.